# csvsimple display bug

Tags: csvsimple

I want to creat a figure using information from à CSV file.

I used the example from the csvsimple manual and replace it with my file to start and I get a display bug: the whole header is written on a string and I can't get rid of it.

I get the error: the first line of the csv file is empty, which is not the case.

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[no head]{energy3.csv}{}{File works fine: \csvcoli, \csvcolii, \csvcoliii\\}
\bigbreak

Diagram from csvsimple manual:
\bigbreak

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\csvreader[head to column names]{data.csv}{}{%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-\thecsvrow cm]
\path [draw] (0,-0.45) rectangle node[font=\bfseries] {\amount} (\amount/1000,0.45);
\node[left] at (0,0) {\land};
\end{scope} }
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigbreak

Diagram with my file: does not work...
\bigbreak

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\csvreader[head to column names]{energy3.csv}{}{%
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-\thecsvrow cm]
    \path [draw] (0,-0.45) rectangle node[font=\bfseries] {\renergy} (\renergy,0.45);
    \node[left] at (0,0) {\carbon};
    \end{scope} }
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigbreak

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

the text data is the following:

```
vehicle,renergy,carbon,trenergy,tcarbon
SUV,$3$,$908$,$57$,$17252$
Citadine,$2.5$,$756$,$47.5$,$14364$
electric-citadine,$2.2$,$648$,$41.8$,$12312$
Hyfit-CIXI,$1.9$,$567$,$36.1$,$10773$
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When I run your example code on the file I don't get the 'line is empty' error. Maybe there is a problem with the line endings or the file encoding. Try to open the file with an advanced text editor, such as Notepad++ on Windows or Sublime Text on Mac, and save the file as UTF-8 with Linux-style line endings, that might help. However, I get a different error that relates to the use of `$` in the file. For printed the values this is fine, but for using them for the width of the box there is a problem that TikZ expects a number (in the `(\renergy,0.45)` part) ...

Comment: ... but instead it finds a number with `$` around it, which is not valid as a value to compute widths. So you need to remove all `$` characters from the csv (for displaying the numbers this does not make a difference anyway).

Comment: I used Notepad++ and the file is working perfectly now! Thank you very much @Marijn! I also took too away the $ signs. I added them in an attempt to fix the problem :P